# What is Purpose of use of ReactiveUI in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-bcl

I am a regular stack overflow user and I have been in the Android community for a while, Recently I am seeing a lot of questions related to ReactiveUI in xamarin and I am not sure what it is, I tried googling about it but did'nt get any satisfactory answer and to be honest i understood nothing:

When I tried researching, I found these links but they didn't help me understand what it(ReactiveUI) is :

https://www.jon-douglas.com/2017/08/16/being-reactive-xamarin-android/

https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/platform/xamarin-android

It would be a great help if someone could help me understand what it actually is and give me a sample or something so, I can learn a little bit about it.

PS: I am a student who just <3 coding so please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell , ReactiveUI is an MVVM framework. You can get all info from the repo as well as samples (see below). (ReactiveUI is not an Android library)

Quote from the GitHub Description

> ReactiveUI is a composable, cross-platform model-view-viewmodel
>   framework for all .NET platforms that is inspired by functional
>   reactive programming which is a paradigm that allows you to abstract
>   mutable state away from your user interfaces and express the idea
>   around a feature in one readable place and improve the testability of
>   your application.

Repository URL for [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI)

Comment: @iamlcarus Why do I always get this negative marking for no reason I don't understand man!

Comment: i wasn't the one down-voted but i can guess this is a too broad question

Comment: Hmm, I just wanted a brief explanation and some links but okay anyways your linked helped thanks a million.